Basement window installation - how deep inside should I frame the window
What is the ideal point to place a 4.5" thick window along the depth of the rough opening?
My goals are:

To make it easy to do finished carpentry on the inside once the windows are installed. I would like to do the finishing myself with fairly simple wood/MDF jambs or other affordable/popular materials.
To ensure the finished depth/window sill on the inside looks pleasing and not awkward.

Here are the quick details. Pics added in the end:

The masonry section of the rough opening is 12" deep
On the inside, right after the masonry, is a 3" gap filled with spray insulation followed by 2x4 framing
Total depth including masonry+ gap+ framing is about 19"
openings/windows height is 1-2" above the ground

My initial thoughts are to have it installed at 2" from the outer edge. Assuming window thickness of 4.5" and a total depth of 19", that would mean the space for a window sill on the inside would be 19 - 4.5 - 2 = 12.5" . Is this too deep? What factors would be impacted by this depth?

Aesthetics?
Insulation? (I live in the east coast (New York area)
Effort involved in finish carpentry - would it somehow be harder to finish carpenter a deeper sill?

Additional details, just in case it helps y'all provide a better answer:

I'm dealing with 2 basement windows. 1 window is for a basement bedroom and the other is at the back of the basement. Kinda a utility area.
Window store rep suggested placing the window framing and consequently the window at about 2" from the outer edge, so the window would be protected from the elements and rain. Window installer will use aluminium capping to close up the gap between the window and the outer edge. It's the inside that I will have to finish myself.





The wisdom is to place the window in line with the building envelope. In this case, since the foundation wall is substantial, anywhere within that area is fine.
If you are not planning to replace the adjoining window, placing the new window in the same location as the other window will make it more aesthetically pleasing and simpler to finish on the inside.
